# Looping through hexadecimals

Tags: c++

When using `GetAsyncKeyState(i)` i needs to be a hexdecimal value between `30` and `59`. Is there a way to loop through hexdecimal values that start with `0x30` - `0x59` so I don't have to type each one of these values into `GetAsyncKeyState(i)` individually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that you're specifying the number in hexadecimal doesn't change the fact that it's still a perfectly normal number. Hexadecimal is just another notation for specifying a value.

```
for (int i=0x30; i<0x59; i++)
   // do your thing.
```

Answer (score 0):

Numbers are just numbers.

```
for (int i=0x30; i<= 0x59; i++)
{
    SHORT WINAPI retval = GetAsyncKeyStates(i);
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
   for (unsigned i = 0x30; i <= 0x59; i += 0x01)
   {
        std::cout << std::hex << "0x" << i << std::endl;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (unsigned i=0x30; i <0x5A; i++)
    printf("%x\n", i);
```